# Flash Builder: debug vs release differences?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

First, the tl;dr background.

I am using Flash Builder 4.7 to build an iOS app using Flex, using an SDK that's a combination of Flex 4.9.1 and AIR 20. Full disclosure; I am still using mx components. In order to comply with Apple's latest App Store requirements, I want to use the latest AIR version. But I tried a couple of times to update the AIR portion of my combinied SDK, failing miserably. So I can't currently use FB's "export release build".

So instead, I am able to build the SWF using my Flex 4.9.1/AIR 20 sdk, do a little hand-editing of the resulting XML file, and then run adt from the latest AIR sdk to do the packaging. This works and makes it through TestFlight just fine. I'm happy (enough) with this solution.

Now, the questions.

1. The SWF I build winds up in bin-debug. Is there any essential difference between that, and whatever FB builds when I do "export release build"?
2. If that's true, is there a way for me to just build the SWF the way "export release build" does it?

thanks.

Comment: The debug build will always run slower than a release build. Not sure what are exact differences though :) I'm wondering how you can do a debug build and not a release one - I thought they are both done with the same SDK that you have set for your project. Also what do you mean by "update the AIR portion"? Get yourself the Apache Flex SDK installer - you can choose any AIR and Flex SDK combination with it. Then add the bundle to your SDKs in FB and use it for compiling

Comment: How are you building the SWF?  The build command in FB, an Ant script, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Mea culpa. And thanks to @philarmon for reminding me about Apache Flex SDK installer. I had completely forgotten about it because I build this project so infrequently. (Mom: that's no excuse. Me: but it's a reason.)

I was building the SWF in FB, but then doing the packaging using a later version of adt. Now I have the latest Flex and AIR and everything is working well again using Export Release Build.

Thanks for listening. Go back to your homes.